# Services inside Thread or the opposite?

Tags: android, multithreading, service

I am just little confused , Services have a higher priority than Thread . and its better to put Thread inside of service if we want to do long time operation.BUT in this question

> [Android Service Stops When App Is Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16651009/android-service-stops-when-app-is-close)

we see that we should put services inside of Thread if we want it to keep it running after we close the app !

If I have Long time operation and I want it not to be closed , which should I use ? Service inside thread or Thread inside Services ?

take a look  ( simmilar question ) 
[Thread inside a service, or service inside a thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422703/thread-inside-a-service-or-service-inside-a-thread)

Comment: *Services have a higher priority than Thread*. Where di you read that and what you mean by priority ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264383/difference-between-service-async-task-thread

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9147195/difference-between-service-and-thread-in-android

Comment: use runOnuiThread!!

Comment: bro , take a look at the link which I commented above ,, most of them said that the services has a better priority than thread